# How do i vertically align the text in the center of jumbotron?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to vertically align the text in the center of my jumbotron but the code i previously used which involved absolute positioning and 50% from top and bottom doesn't seem to work for this

Here is my html

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center"><span class="first">UZER</span><span class="last">JAMAL</span></h1>
        <p class="text-center" id="respon">Responsive web designer</p>
        <p class="text-center" id="langs">HTML - CSS - BOOTSTRAP - JQUERY</p>
    </container>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.jumbotron{
height:100vh;
background:url('./Images/Jumbo.jpg') no-repeat center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
background-size:cover;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
top:0;
z-index:-100;
}

h1{
margin-bottom: -0.7em;
}
h1 .first{
color:white;
font-family:secretcode;
font-size:2em;
}

h1 .last{
color: #bd902e;
font-family:aku;
font-size:1.7em;
}

.jumbotron #respon{
font-family:geosans;
color:white;
font-size:4em;
margin-bottom:-0.2em;
}

.jumbotron #langs{
font-family:geosans;
color:#bd902e;
font-size:2em;
}
```

Also is there a way to bring the h1 and p vertically closer to each other without using negative margin? I don't think using -0.7em is the right way to do it

Code[**Jsfiddle.net**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/zhuv5ukb/)

Comment: would be better if you create a fiddle for that

Comment: this is fiddle.net code https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/zhuv5ukb/

Comment: Thanks, i added it in first post too

Comment: i didn't get you..what is the problem?\

Comment: The text is not in middle vertically https://i.gyazo.com/5772a7521e5b9d30c4a532ba16b389a6.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
.jumbotron{
    height:100vh;
    background:url('./Images/Jumbo.jpg') no-repeat center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    z-index:-100;
    display:flex;
    display-direction:column;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `top:50%` and `transform: translate(-50%, 0)` css property

```
.jumbotron {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('./Images/Jumbo.jpg') no-repeat center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  z-index: -100;
}
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/zhuv5ukb/1/

Comment: That's what i used before but for some reason it doesn't work now

Comment: and what is the reason?

Comment: No idea.. Adding that code to the jumbotron css makes the entire jumbrotron move, not just the text and adding it to the text (by putting all the text in a div) does nothing

Answer (score 0):

`line-height:0` is what you're looking for I think.